# Php cookie isn't setting after a form action redirect

Tags: php, html, setcookie

I'm trying to do a remember me. I'm having an issue were the cookie isn't setting after a form action redirect.

I know this is not the safest way to store a password but it does matter because this is just a simple page that has no information that is important.

```
if(isset($_POST['signin']))
{
        setcookie("cid",$id,time()+60*60);
        setcookie("cpass",$pass,time()+60*60);
        }
?>


<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<hr/>
<table align="center"> 
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo @$err;?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Your email</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"  value="<?php echo @$_COOKIE['cid'];?>" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Your password</th>
    <td><input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" value="<?php echo @$_COOKIE['cpass'];?>" required/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Stay Signed In</th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="signin" value="SignIn"/></td>
</tr>
</table>    
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: your html is broken. `</body>` terminates the document, and you cannot have more html after the body is closed.

Comment: the @ symbols aren't helping during testing. they're error suppressors. Turn error reporting on http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and view your HTML source.

Comment: Thanks guys! That was a mistake. I do have those corrections already in my code. I just pasted and edited it wrong here! Sorry. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this lines in,

```
if(isset($_POST['signin'])) 
{
    setcookie("cid",$id,time()+60*60);
    setcookie("cpass",$pass,time()+60*60);
    }
?>
```

in `login.php`

Since your action of the form is `login.php`.

---

```
</table>    
</form>
```

This is also wrong, it should be

```
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Yup! Just waiting for the timer to allow me to! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad i could help you:)